# Recurrence of derangement polynomials and eulerian polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, combinations

we want to prove this identity
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i} d_i(x) (x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-i}) = xA_n(x)$$
we define the $n$-th Eulerian polynomial as follows:
$$
    A_n(x) := \sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n} x^{exc(\sigma)}
$$
The set of all derangements on $n$ elements is usually denoted by $\mathfrak{D}_n$. $d_n(x)$ is defined by
$$d_n(x) := \sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{D}_n} x^{\operatorname{exc}(\sigma)}
$$
where $\operatorname{exc}(\sigma):=|\{i\in [n]:\sigma_i>i\}|$ denotes the number of $excedances$ of $\sigma$.